# Cниженный стиль речи?

Tags: стилистика

Относятся ли к нормативной лексике выражения " во сколько", "со скольки" и "до скольки"?

Comment: Считаю эти замечательные выражения плоть от плоти нашего креативного по сути языка. Если имеют право на существование как литературные такие выражения, как "во сколько раз", "на сколько меньше/больше", и, даже, "поскольку", то почему мы должны отказывать в кодификации выше перечисленным?

Answer (score 2):

Слово **СКОЛЬКО** склоняется: скольких, скольким,по скольку и по сколько, сколькими, о скольких. Соответственно, **во сколько** - форма винительного падежа, соответствующая литературной норме. Примеры: *Во сколько раз выросла (уменьшилась) прибыль? Во сколько (часов) встречаемся?*
**Со скольки, до скольки** - формы, не соответствующие литературной норме, но имеющие широкое хождение в разговорной речи.
Кстати, слово **поскольку** (слитное написание) - не местоименное наречие, а союз, потому и пишется слитно. Раздельное написание (предлог + числительное) необходимо, например, в таком контексте: *По сколько ложек сахара ты положил нам в кофе?*